# switch between if/else blocks on error

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling, try-catch

I'm looking for a way to switch between an if and an else block when an error occurs. For example:

```
cout << "Enter 1 or 2 as your choice...";
cin >> choice;

if(choice==1) {

//do something here

//if error occurs....

} else if(choice==2) {

//switch to this else block

}
```

I've played around with try/throw/catch but it appears that the catch has to follow the try statement. Any ideas/suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: You could put the body of the `else if` part in a function and then call it from both places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you could just not have an "else":

```
int error = 0;

if( choice==1 ) {

    // Something happens
    error = 1;

}
if( error == 1 || choice == 2 ) {
    // Do things
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When I come across this situation, I create a separate function with the code wanted in the `else` block. Then I *call* the function whenever needed (if an error occurs, and in the `else` block).

Answer (score 1):

You really want to split that in to two different conditional blocks.  After all, you don't really mean "else".

```
if(choice==1) 
{  
//if error occurs....  
} 
if(choice==2 || error) 
{
  //switch to this block  
}
```